# pandas convert strings to float for multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and trying to figure out how to convert multiple columns which are formatted as strings to float64's.  Currently I'm doing the below, but it seems like apply() or applymap() should be able to accomplish this task even more efficiently...unfortunately I'm a bit too much of a rookie to figure out how.  Currently the values are percentages formatted as strings like '15.5%'

```
for column in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']:
    data[column] = data[column].str.rstrip('%').astype('float64') / 100
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting in 0.11.1 (coming out this week), replace has a new option to replace with a regex, so this becomes possible

```
In [14]: df = DataFrame('10.0%',index=range(100),columns=range(10))

In [15]: df.replace('%','',regex=True).astype('float')/100
Out[15]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 10 columns):
0    100  non-null values
1    100  non-null values
2    100  non-null values
3    100  non-null values
4    100  non-null values
5    100  non-null values
6    100  non-null values
7    100  non-null values
8    100  non-null values
9    100  non-null values
dtypes: float64(10)
```

And a bit faster

```
In [16]: %timeit df.replace('%','',regex=True).astype('float')/100
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop

 In [18]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: float(x[:-1]))/100
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I implement this for specific columns? `df['Column1'].replace('%','',regex=True).astype('float')/100` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.applymap(lambda x:float(x.rstrip('%'))/100)
```

Answer (score 1):

answering a comment in the accepted answer: 
for specific columns make sure you don't do it inplace.

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].replace('%','',regex=True).astype('float')/100
```