# Pandas dataframe converting specific columns from string to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do some simple analyses on the Kenneth French industry portfolios (first time with Pandas/Python), data is in txt format (see link in the code). Before I can do computations, first want to load it in a Pandas dataframe properly, but I've been struggling with this for hours:

```
import urllib.request
import os.path
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# paths
url = 'http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/48_Industry_Portfolios_CSV.zip'
csv_name = '48_Industry_Portfolios.CSV'
local_zipfile = '{0}/data.zip'.format(os.getcwd())
local_file = '{0}/{1}'.format(os.getcwd(), csv_name)

# download data
if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
    print('Downloading and unzipping file!')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, local_zipfile)
    zipfile.ZipFile(local_zipfile).extract(csv_name, os.path.dirname(local_file))

# read from file
df = pd.read_csv(local_file,skiprows=11)
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0' : 'dates'}, inplace=True)

# build new dataframe
first_stop = df['dates'][df['dates']=='201412'].index[0]
df2 = df[:first_stop]

# convert date to datetime object
pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'], format = '%Y%m')
df2.index = df2.dates
```

All the columns, except dates, represent financial returns. However, due to the file formatting, these are now strings. According to Pandas docs, this should do the trick:

```
df2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

But the columns remain strings. Other suggestions are to loop over the columns (see for example [pandas convert strings to float for multiple columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643695/pandas-convert-strings-to-float-for-multiple-columns-in-dataframe)):

```
for d in df2.columns:
if d is not 'dates':
    df2[d] = df2[d].map(lambda x: float(x)/100)
```

But this gives me the following warning:

```
 home/<xxxx>/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.5/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  try:
```

I have read the documentation on views vs copies, but having difficulty to understand why it is a problem in my case, but not in the code snippets in the question I linked to. Thanks

Edit:

```
df2=df2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Does the trick, although I receive a depreciation warning (strangely enough that is not in the docs at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html)

Some of df2:

```
     dates    Agric    Food     Soda     Beer     Smoke    Toys     Fun    \
dates                                                                           
192607  192607     2.37     0.12   -99.99    -5.19     1.29     8.65     2.50   
192608  192608     2.23     2.68   -99.99    27.03     6.50    16.81    -0.76   
192609  192609    -0.57     1.58   -99.99     4.02     1.26     8.33     6.42   
192610  192610    -0.46    -3.68   -99.99    -3.31     1.06    -1.40    -5.09   
192611  192611     6.75     6.26   -99.99     7.29     4.55     0.00     1.82
```

Edit2: the solution is actually more simple than I thought:

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'], format = '%Y%m')
df2 = df2.astype(float)/100
```

Comment: silly question did you assign back the result of `convert_objects`? e.g. `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`?

Comment: Can you add what your `df2` looks like? Edit your question with at least a partial view of the data frame.

Comment: @EdChum: that works, although I do not understand why I would need to assign the result, isn't that stored? Renaming columns is stored as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects) as there is no `inplace` param:

```
df2=df2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

you refer to the `rename` method but that one has an `inplace` param which you set to `True`.

Most operations in pandas return a copy and some have `inplace` param, `convert_objects` is one that does not. This is probably because if the conversion fails then you don't want to blat over your data with `NaNs`.

Also the deprecation warning is to split out the different conversion routines, presumably so you can specialise the params e.g. format string for datetime etc..

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added the solution, just realized I had the same issue with converting the dates. Maybe a bit off-topic, but suppose I would only want to convert a single column from strings to floats (as I tried to do in my original question), how can I avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning?

Comment: You should filter the df for the object dtypes and then cast these using `astype` so something like `cols = list(df) cols.pop('dates' for col in cols: df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float) / 100` should work but really `convert_objects` is the way to go

Comment: Unfortunately `convert_objects` is `Deprecated since version 0.21.0.` so another methods should be preferred nowadays

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following to force convert everything into floats:

```
df2=df2.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert specific column to float(or any numerical type for that matter) by

```
df["column_name"] = pd.to_numeric(df["column_name"])
```

Posting this because `pandas.convert_objects` is deprecated in pandas 0.20.1